# Getting Dropbox to sync over SSH

Tags: ssh, dropbox

I am using Scientific Linux on my office computer and home laptop. I was usually signed in before I leave my office so when I made a change over SSH on my office computer, Dropbox would automatically sync the change.

But this time I rebooted my office computer using SSH with `/sbin/reboot`, and after signing in again it would no longer update Dropbox. I guess this is because Dropbox needs to be signed in once locally to continue syncing.

How can I set Dropbox syncing remotely over SSH on my office computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [dropbox command line tool](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI) that allows you to perform all sorts of tasks, including stopping and starting dropbox.

You could include a short snippet in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (depending on what you use), that checks if dropbox is already running, and if not, starts it:

```
~/bin/dropbox.py running
[ $? -eq 0 ] && ~/bin/dropbox.py start
```

Comment: For my Centos box dropbox start works as installed command then i use python script just for checking state `~/mybin/dropbox.py running 

[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "starting dropbox... " && dropbox start; 

echo "dropbox is started";`